# Change Version Of Material 1.1.0 to 1.3.0

Tags: android, styles, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

**And my Second Question :**
I use a TextInputLayout :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout              
  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColorHint="@color/LightBlue"              
 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/selector"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="3dp"
                app:startIconTint="@color/white">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfPlayer_txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColor="@color/gold" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**The Styles file**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" 
  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Thistle</item>
                   <!-- use in get player information -->
       <item name="CustomTextStyle">@style/Widget.App. TextInputLayout. 
       OutlinedBox</item>
  </style>


    <style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" 
     parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">20dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">20dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">20dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:hint">Number of player</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/card1</item>
        <item name="startIconDrawable">@drawable/ic_people</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" 
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/player_information</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">15dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">15dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">15dp</item>
        <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="startIconDrawable">@drawable/player</item>
        <item name="startIconTint">@color/gold</item>
        <item name="elevation">5dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
        <itemname="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App. 
         TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/AntiqueWhite</item>
        <!-- .... -->
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"  
    
   parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
        <!-- to change the cursor color -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

**That is my selector file**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/DarkSeaGreen" 
    android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>
    </selector>
```

**and Attrs**

```
 <resources>
   <attr name="customTextInputStyle" format="reference" />
   <attr name="CustomTextStyle" formet ="reference"/>
   </resources>
```

When I change the version of the material 1.1.0 to 1.3.0 ,The shape of The text input layout[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZJlS.png) I created before is distorted. It became wider than it was before. I could not find the reason for this change.As you can see in the picture, the text inputlayout is very wide and the hinttext still looks black on the back.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **main** issue is in the ThemeOverlay. You have to add the parent `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox`.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

It is **needed** because the default style `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` which you are extending has defined a own `materialThemeOverlay` and
without the parent dependency you are losing the default behaviour.

Also in your xml layout **remove** `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"`. You don't need it because you are already using `materialThemeOverlay` in the style and the theme defined in the xml layout overrides it and this theme overlay is wrong.

Also:

- use a min width because you are using a big corner radius `15dp`

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

- Finally the color used by the hint:

```
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red600Dark</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/teal_700</item>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Final layout:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout              
      style="@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:startIconTint="@color/white">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/numberOfPlayer_txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColor="@color/gold" />

   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

with:

```
<style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_stroke_selector</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">15dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">15dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">15dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">15dp</item>
    <item name="startIconDrawable">@drawable/ic_...</item>
    <item name="startIconTint">@color/...</item>
    <item name="elevation">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/....</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/....</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I added picture to problem

Comment: I just need to do    `<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"> ` Am I right ?

Comment: @Neo Yes. Remove `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"` in the xml layout. You don't need it and it is wrong. Pay attention to `wrapContent` because with an huge corner radius the field can be heigher.

Comment: Why I need to add  `<item name="materialThemeOverlay">
  @style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox
</item> ` to inside  `<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
</style>` ?

Comment: can u share your layout and styles code for that problem ?

Comment: `<style name="..."
 parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout .OutlinedBox"> ` This way I can create a different Style and use `style = "@ style / ..."`  in the layout, right?

Comment: I'm getting this error "Infinite loop '? When trying to solve TextAppearance: Creation may not be correct." Is it a problem ?

Comment: Where do you have this issue?

Comment: There were red exclamation points in the Layout and when I clicked there were 2 renderings. Render In had such error message.